# 16352 is the max length .NET Webservices can return Jsonp?

Tags: .net, web-services, jsonp

I have a webservice that returns Json values to a javascript caller. As I couldn't get .NET to return JSON format, (even though I have set it as ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json) (also, this is not a cross domain request) I have have to set the javascript to receive it in JSONP instead.

This is working fine until the character length of the return value starts to grow. Strange errors starts popping up. Took me several hours and at the very end, the only pattern I can find is this:

After a 'magical' 16352 characters, it will insert a ");jsonp1349260900225(" in between the returned values. (1349260900225 <-- this changes but the format remains the same) And this continues for every 16352 characters thereafter. On the javascript side, it just takes the respond and tried to parse it as normal causing errors appearing at random areas of the output.

Anybody faced this problem before? 16352 characters is not really a lot and I simply couldn't reduce the length to sidestep this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Here is a snippet of the returned value from firebug:

> lign=\u0027absMiddle\u0027 /\u003e\u003cimg
>   src=\u0027http://squarelet.com/images/smiley/Smile.gif\u0027
>   align=\u0027absMiddle\u0027 /\u003e \u003cimg
>   src=\u0027http://squarelet.com/images/smiley/Smile.gif\u0027
>   align=);jsonp1349260900225(u0027absMiddle\u0027 /\u003e\u003cimg
>   src=\u0027http://squarelet.com/images/smiley/Smile.gif\u0027
>   align=\u0027absMiddle\u0027 /\u003e \u003cimg
>   src=\u0027http://squarelet.com/images/smiley/Smile.gif\u0027
>   align=\u0027absMiddle\u0027 /\u003e\u003cimg
>   src=\u0027http://squarelet.com/images/smiley/Smile.gif\u0027 align=\

This is the webservice that returns the values:

```
<WebMethod()> _
<ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet:=True, ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)> _
Public Function L_C_H(ByVal CSI As String, ByVal CCI As String) As List(Of SquareLet.ChatManagement.Chat)

    Return SquareLet.ChatManagement.Chat.LoadHistory(Guid.Parse(CSI), Guid.Parse(CCI))

End Function
```

Comment: I don't see you returning jsonp ... it looks to me like the webserver returns plain json .. (Btw. The lenght of json can be specified in web.config <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="xxx"/> the default is 2097152 characters)

Comment: The data from firebug is show it's Jsonp (although I dont know why). I understand there is a default size. But why is it at 16352 char only? Dang it :(

Answer (score 0):

You must [set MaxJsonLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763183%28VS.100%29.aspx) to a bigger value. That property is the one that is probably limiting you.